# Separate elements of the list in R and create a new list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list called `k` which has three separate `data.frame`'s embedded in it: `ts1`, `ts2` and `ts3`. Each of the `data.frame`'s have a column structure of: `X1`,`X2`, .... `X10`.

I would like to create a new list with the same `data.frame` names (`ts1`,`ts2` and `ts3`) but the `data.frame`'s only contain the `X1` column.

So, under:

```
set.seed(1337)
ts1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
ts2 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
ts3 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

k<- list(ts1=ts1,ts2=ts2,ts3=ts3)
```

The output should be:

> $ts1    X1 1   1 2   1 3   0 4   0 5   0 6   0 7   1 8   0 9   0 10  0
>
> $ts2    X1 1   0 2   0 3   1 4   1 5   0 6   0 7   0 8   0 9   0 10  0
>
> $ts3    X1 1   1 2   0 3   0 4   0 5   1 6   0 7   1 8   0 9   0 10  1

I would prefer this to be done using lapply in `R`.

Comment: `lapply(k, '[', 1)` and since you have mapply tagged `mapply('[', k, 1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Retain List Structure**

To retain the list structure & `data.frame` names, use:

```
helper = function(x,p){
  x[,p, drop =  F]
}

m = lapply(k,FUN=helper, p = "X1")
```

`p` allows you to pick the column names

`drop = F` prevents the information from being dropped.

Using `lapply` returns a `list` with the `data.frame` structure as requested.

**Merged Total `data.frame`**

On the first glance of the question, I wrote the following.  Above is an edit with the appropriate response.

The best approach is to use `rbindlist()` from `data.table`

```
install.packages("data.table")
library("data.table")
total = rbindlist(k)

x1 = total[,"X1", with = F]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this does not answer my question, I would like to create a new list still preserving the element name ts1, ts2 and ts3 except that it should contain only X1

Comment: @forecaster thanks for the clarification, please see edit.